# Stripe : customize form

Tags: stripe-payments

after some research, I have not found how to customize the Stripe V3 payment form.

I would like to be able to write each field of the form myself. I think that because of this, the javascript code must be different, but I have not found an example.

Has anyone ever done that? If so, can you show me the html and javascript code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) (Stripe.js v3), each input field is created by Stripe.js and runs in its own iframe.

If you want to create the fields yourself, you can still use [Stripe.js v2](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/v2) but note that you would no longer be eligible for PCI SAQ-A and would instead need to file under SAQ-A EP which is more complex.

You can find more information about PCI compliance [here](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance).